# Fragment backstack with NavDeeplinkbuilder usgin Navigation components

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-navigation

I have single activity app using navigation components. I have three fragments: WelcomeScreen -> HomeScreen -> MovieDetailsScreen. I use Notification in my app and when I click notification, it navigates me to MovieDetailsScreen but when I press back arrow, it navigats me  to WelcomeScreen. I do not want this behavor. When I pres back arrow, I want me to navigate to HomeScreen and when I press back arrow again, I want the app to be closed. How to delete the WelcomeScreen from backstack?

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
              .setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)
              .setDestination(R.id.MovieDetailsScreen)
              .setArguments(bundle)
              .createPendingIntent()

          NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
              ....
          .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
              .build()
```

Comment: Is `WelcomeScreen` the start destination of your graph? That's always the wrong thing to do as specifically called out in the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination). Did you read the [guide to conditionally navigate to a screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, the `WelcomeScreen` is the start destination of my graph